# python How to zoom sheet in xlwings

Tags: python, xlwings

I need to use zoom in only xlwings, below code is not worked.
Plz help me....

```
import xlwings as xw

xw.App(visible=True)
workbook = xw.Book(r'zoom.xlsx')
sheet = workbook.sheets.active

# sheet.api.ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100
# sheet.app.api.active_window.zoom.set(100)
# excel.ActiveWindow.Zoom = 80
# sheet.api.PageSetup.Zoom = 100
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import xlwings as xw

app = xw.apps.active
app.api.ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
app.api.ActiveWindow.Zoom = 80
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to loop through the list of sheets, activate each sheet, and call 'app.api.ActiveWindow.Zoom', as below:

```
for sht in wb.sheets:
    sht.activate()
    sht.book.app.api.ActiveWindow.Zoom = 80
```